# "Skip this page" without Flash/Javascript possible?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

So, we've probably all seen this kind of websites with a flash intro, which could be skipped by clicking anywhere, sending the user to index.html or something.

The question is: Can this be done without Flash, or even without javascript?
'Cause it's probably not the best idea to make the very first page useless for some of your visitors due to lacking flash plugin or something blocking javascript (noscript plugin, for example).

Any idea?
thanks.

Comment: You need some language to handle the `click` event on the page, so without Flash or JavaScript, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Cause it's probably not the best idea
>   to make the very first page useless
>   for some of your visitors due to
>   lacking flash plugin or something
>   blocking javascript (noscript plugin,
>   for example).

You should show the "flash intro" using JavaScript and also check that Flash is available.

That way, only users who have both JavaScript and Flash enabled will be *subjected* to the "flash intro".

Users with JavaScript disabled will simply see the actual page.